# How to configure XA transaction timeout with Amazon MQ (ActiveMQ "Classic")?

Tags: activemq-classic

I'm trying to set up JMS client to use XA transactions with variable timeouts, talking to Amazon MQ with ActiveMQ "Classic" engine.

Calling `jmsSession.getXAResource().setTransactionTimeout(timeOut)` returns `false`, indicating that that didn't succeed. This means that sending `SESS_XA_SET_TIMEOUT_RESP` to the broker resulted in `!OK`, but I don't see any logs that would explain why (for that matter, so far I can't see any logs from the broker). The same XA logic code works just fine with Artemis.

I found [Resource Manager Configuration](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/transaction-config.html) that says that [default] transaction timeout can be set in the broker configuration file, however it's unclear how exactly this is to be specified, the [configuration file schema](http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core-5.15.4-schema.html) has no mention of `transaction-timeout` property, nor can I see any "generic" property list where can it be specified.

So two-part question, really:

1. How do I configure the "default" transaction timeout mentioned in [Resource Manager Configuration](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/transaction-config.html)
2. Is there a particular reason I can't change the transaction timeout programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

OK, the short answer - ActiveMQ Classic (5.x) doesn't support distributed transaction timeouts.

I apparently was looking at Artemis's client code, instead of the Classic's. In the Classic client, `TransactionContext.setTransactionTimeout()` simply returns false:

```
@Override
public boolean setTransactionTimeout(int seconds) throws XAException {
    return false;
}
```

As far as I can understand, this means that XA transactions never timeout, but I can't find any documentation that talks about any of it.